# Launching protractor with chrome guest mode

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I need to launch multiple Chrome browser instances with guest profile from protractor. My Current configuration is like -

```js
multiCapabilityArray[i] = {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
   'args': ['incognito', '--no-sandbox']
  }
 }
```

I am looking for something like following -

```
multiCapabilityArray[i] = {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['incognito', '--no-sandbox'],
        'prefs': {enter-something-here-to-make-the-magic-happen}
    }
}
```

Please share if there is any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below chrome setup in your test.

```
'browserName': 'chrome',
'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['--incognito', '--no-sandbox']
}
```

Just add `--` before `incognito`.
Hope above solution helps you

## 0506

Comment: I will try and get back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @madhan! It did work for me. Just curious, what was the implication without the '--', I did not get any error while using it...

Comment: @DebasishMukherjee It is the syntax for adding chrome option. Please mark it as correct if it helped you.

Comment: This process did work for me. However I had to use different capabilities for each of my login. I am still working on the code. Will share in this thread once I have done it.